# How can I create a variable that performs the setter of another variable?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following code in which I set the value of the `DTO` in each function:

```java
if (fromDate.isBefore(dateAct)) {
    employeeDashboardDto.setAbsenceDays(absenceDays);
    employeeDashboardDto.setIntensiveWorkedDays(intensiveWorkedDays);
    employeeDashboardDto.setWorkedDays(workedDays);
} else {
    employeeDashboardDto.setAbsenceDays(absenceDays);
    employeeDashboardDto.setIntensiveWorkedDays(intensiveWorkedDays);
}
```

Is it possible to create a variable to set the value of the `DTO` and use it in both functions? So I avoid repeating the same set:

Example:

```java
abs = employeeDashboardDto.setAbsenceDays(absenceDays);
    
if (fromDate.isBefore(dateAct)) {
   abs;
} else {
    abs;
}
```

Comment: Simply add `employeeDashboardDto.setAbsenceDays(absenceDays);` at the end of the if-else block because the same value gets repeated in both if and else block.

Comment: I don't understand, do I have to remove the if-else block to get them out?

Comment: See, both the answers simplify the writing style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write like this.

```
if (fromDate.isBefore(dateAct)) {
    
    
    employeeDashboardDto.setWorkedDays(workedDays);
} else {
    
    // Some other operations
    //Set some other values
}
employeeDashboardDto.setIntensiveWorkedDays(intensiveWorkedDays);
employeeDashboardDto.setAbsenceDays(absenceDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified to this:

```
    if (fromDate.isBefore(dateAct)) {
        employeeDashboardDto.setWorkedDays(workedDays);
    } 

    employeeDashboardDto.setAbsenceDays(absenceDays);
    employeeDashboardDto.setIntensiveWorkedDays(intensiveWorkedDays);
```